# I was trying to add the functionality that when i click on the selected radio button again it should get deselected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, react-fullstack

I was trying to add the functionality, that when I click on the selected radio button again, it should get deselected, but my logic is not working, that what I have did in handleRadioChange function.

So the expected behaviour should be, that when I click on selected radio button again it should get deselected.

As this is a reusable component and I want that functionality. Any Suggestions will be helpful.

code

```
import {
  FormControl,
  FormControlLabel,
  Radio,
  RadioGroup,
} from '@material-ui/core'
import clsx from 'clsx'
import React from 'react'
import { useStyles } from './index.styles'
import OpenInNewIcon from '@mui/icons-material/OpenInNew'
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash'
import { RadioButtonType } from 'labrav-react-components'
import { RadioButtonGroupMapping } from 'labrav-react-components'

export type RadioButtonsProps = {
  checkedValue?: { key: string; value: string }
  handleChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
  radioButtonMappings: RadioButtonGroupMapping[]
  customChild?: JSX.Element
}
export const NewRadioButtons: React.FC<RadioButtonsProps> = ({
  checkedValue,
  handleChange,
  radioButtonMappings,
  customChild,
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  
   const handleRadioChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const selectedValue = event.target.value
    const isSameValue = selectedValue === checkedValue?.value
    if (isSameValue) {
     handleChange({
      target: { value: ''},
    } as React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)
    } else {
      handleChange(event)
    }
  }


  return (
    <FormControl>
      <RadioGroup
        aria-labelledby="radio-buttons-group"
        name="radio-buttons-group"
        value={checkedValue ? checkedValue?.value :''}
        onChange={handleRadioChange}
        data-testid="radio-group"
        row
        className={classes.root}
      >
        {radioButtonMappings.map(radioButtonMapping => {
          return (
            <div
              key={radioButtonMapping.key}
            >
              <FormControlLabel
                value={radioButtonMapping.key}
                control={<Radio className={classes.radio}  />}
                label={radioButtonMapping.label}
                className={classes.radioLabel}
                data-testid="radio-label"
                disabled={radioButtonMapping?.disabled || false}
              />
              {radioButtonMapping.key !== RadioButtonType.CUSTOM &&
                !isEmpty(radioButtonMapping.url) && (
                  <a
                    style={{ height: '18px' }}
                    href={radioButtonMapping.url}
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    <OpenInNewIcon className={classes.openNewIcon} />
                  </a>
                )}
              {checkedValue &&(checkedValue.key === radioButtonMapping.key &&
              radioButtonMapping.type === RadioButtonType.CUSTOM) ? (
                <>{customChild}</>
              ) : null}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  )
}
```